# bootstrap submenu and pull-left gap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, submenu

to make a submenu in bootstrap v2 with the submenu appearing on the right side of the main menu, the manual suggests using .pull-left, but it seems that in this case the submenu is rendered at an offset at least equal to the main menu width. if the submenu is not as wide there's a gap between the submenu and the main menu.

see http://jsfiddle.net/5BUXu/1/

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu" style="display: block; position: static; margin-bottom: 5px; *width: 180px;">
<li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
<li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
<li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something that is a really really really long string here</a></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li class="dropdown-submenu pull-left"> <a tabindex="-1" href="#">More options</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">shorter things</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">shorter things</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">shorter things</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

is it possible to eliminate the gap?

a hacky workaround i tried is to set the width of the submenu ul element to 100%. it works to eliminate the gap, but i'd prefer a solution that keeps the natural width of the submenu.

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing the same issue when the dropdown menu was wider than the submenu. The problem is that the submenu's position is calculated from its left side, so I fixed it like this:

```
.left-submenu {
    float: none;
}

.left-submenu > .dropdown-menu {
    border-radius: 6px 0px 6px 6px;
    left: auto;
    margin-left: 10px;
    right: 98%;
}
```

Using the `.left-submenu` class instead of `.pull-left` on the dropdown-submenu will solve your issue. You can see it live here: http://jsfiddle.net/5BUXu/5/